# Offline install of a flatpak application

Tags: software-installation, flatpak

I am working in a locked-down corporate environment and I need to install the latest MonoDevelop (http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/) in an totally offline environment. I have the ability to access the web to do whatever I need to, but I need to somehow generate a set of files that I can carry over with a flash drive or other media from which I can perform the install on a RHEL 7.2 machine.

The `flatpak build-bundle` command looks promising, but it doesn't seem to be capable of working from an online repository. Since MonoDevelop installs from a flatpakref I haven't been able to figure out how exactly to do this. Do I need to mirror the entire repo locally? If so, because the flatpakref file also references the runtime Gnome repo, do I need to mirror that as well?

What I would really love is to just install this and then somehow export a bundle. For previous versions of MonoDevelop we were able to use repotrack to find all the relevant RPMs and bring those over manually, but now that they have moved to flatpak it doesn't seem so easy.

Answer (score 2):

Update Nov 2020: In Flatpak 1.7.1+ there is a new cmdline option
`--sideload-repo` and different paths for offline repos. Also re-worded answer
to try and bring size down overall.

---

Update June 2020: I was not specific enough about the location of the offline
repo. For avoidance of doubt the full path to the summary file in an offline
repo should be: `/.ostree/repos.d/myoffline_repo/summary`. Clarified
instructions below. Also discovered that links for offline repos must be on the
same filesystem.

---

Update May 2020: make note of two issues that make using flatpak offline
painful.

---

Please note two issues that make working with offline flatpak repos difficult:

1. There is a bug that causes problems when installing flatpaks that use
   extensions from an offline repo: [Flatpak gets confused when the same ref of
   an extension exists in two
   repositories](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/3128) When working
   offline you create a second repo to mirror the online one so this bug cannot
   be avoided. It means required extensions are not installed on the offline
   machine. The best way to check if this is the case is to compare what is
   installed on a healthy online system versus the offline one `flatpak list`.
   Significant differences may indicate additional extensions required on the
   offline system. Flatpak will list what it's about to install when you install
   something so you can compare this way too. On the offline system it will fail
   to list the extensions.
2. Some flatpaks attempt to download files (extra-data) during installation
   which will fail if the host is always offline: [Fails to download libopenh264
   when installing offline from flatpak
   create-usb](https://gitlab.com/freedesktop-sdk/openh264-extension/-/issues/5)
   One example of this is the openh264 extension that during install downloads
   from cisco.com. You can circumvent this by placing the required downloads in
   the right place for flatpak to find them without downloading:
   '~/.local/share/flatpak/extra-data/$SHA256/$FILENAME'. However the exact
   filename depends on the flatpak's config. One way to find out is to install
   the problematic flaptak with strace and look for ENOENT against extra-data
   paths. The shas and filenames will change between releases/updates so you
   will have to update it on an on-going basis.

Blog post ["About Flatpak installations"
(blogs.gnome.org)](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2018/08/26/about-flatpak-installations/)
by mclasen on the official GNOME blog says this is exactly what `flatpak create-usb` is for - it creates a mirror of a remote repo containing the app and
will bundle all dependencies too. You can even repeat the `create-usb` step
multiple times to push more apps into the new repo before transferring to
offline hosts. You don't have to use a USB stick either, you can transfer the
repo however you like to the target machine.

Start on the machine where you'll build your offline repo: the remote you're
mirroring will need a collection ID and a subsequent flatpak update. If you're
trying to package an app from flathub the author gives an example:

```bsh
# Configure the remote
flatpak remote-modify --collection-id=org.flathub.Stable flathub
# Force an update
flatpak update
# Package up GIMP (for example)
flatpak create-usb ./ org.gimp.GIMP
```

The author explains why these steps are needed:

> If you don’t add the collection ID to your remote configuration, you will be
> greeted by an error saying “Remote ‘flathub’ does not have a collection ID
> set”. If you omit the flatpak update, the error will say “No such branch
> (org.flathub.Stable, ostree-metadata) in repository”.

Despite the talk of USB sticks this will leave you with a repo under `.ostree`
in the current directory.

Now that you have an offline repo you want to use it when installing flatpaks. Here
there are differences depending on your Flatpak version.

#### Flatpak 1.7.1+

Starting from Flatpak 1.7.1 the latest documentation on [USB
Drives](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/usb-drives.html) refers to offline
repos as sideload repos. The docs say you can either specify `--sideload-repo`
at the command line, use their new systemd units or

> Alternatively, it’s possible to specify sideload sources using symbolic links
> placed in system-wide or user-specific directories and such sources will then
> be used for all Flatpak operations without the need for a --sideload-repo
> option.

This refers to the [flatpak command
reference](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak)
which reads:

> Such repositories are configured by creating symlinks to the sideload sources
> in the sideload-repos subdirectory of the installation directory (i.e.
> typically /var/lib/flatpak/sideload-repos). Additionally symlinks can be
> created in /run/flatpak/sideload-repos which is a better location for
> non-persistent sources (as it is cleared on reboot). These symlinks can point
> to either the directory given to flatpak create-usb which by default writes to
> the subpath .ostree/repo, or directly to an ostree repo.

The best option for a permanent setup is to make the symbolic links under
`/var/lib` then. As an emample Flatpak should be able to reach the summmary of
your `offline_flatpak` repo here:
`/var/lib/flatpak/sideload-repos/offline_flatpak/summary`

The systemd unit mentioned earlier just seems to scan newly inserted drives and
put symlinks under `/run/flatpak/...` This might be enough if you are genuinely
using USB drives.

#### Flatpak <1.7.1

Flatpak has a repo finder mechanism that will consider not just remotes but
certain local paths when looking for repositories or their mirrors.  You just
need to put the mirror repo in the right place on your target machine for
flatpak to use it. Flatpak will search each mount for a repo at the following
dirs:

```
.ostree/repo
ostree/repo
.ostree/repos.d/
ostree/repos.d/
```

So you can either copy your repo to a USB and stick it in the target machine or
copy the files to e.g. `/.ostree/repo` to use the root filesystem.

To be clear, if you chose to use `/.ostree/repos.d` then the summary file for
your offline repo should be found at `/.ostree/repos.d/myoffline_repo/summary`.

You can also use a symbolic link in any of these dirs and place the real files
elsewhere e.g.

```bsh
mkdir -p /.ostree/repos.d
ln -s /home/user/Downloads/.ostree/repo /.ostree/repos.d/myoffline_repo
```

However note the link must to the SAME filesystem or else flatpak will not use it.

Also note flatpak will favour the most up-to-date repo it can find, whichever
that is.

#### Finally

You must still remember to add the original repo to the target machine of course
(flathub in this instance) - and set the collection ID. This is because
everything in the mirror repo is stored by reference to that original collection
ID. On the target machine:

```bsh
flatpak remote-add flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak remote-modify --collection-id=org.flathub.Stable flathub
```

If the target is truly offline you can add a remote from a .flatpakrepo file,
instead of using a URL:

```bsh
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub flathub.flatpakrepo
# Download file from https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Then you can go ahead and install as normal on the target machine:

```bsh
flatpak install flathub org.gimp.GIMP
```

If there any problems:

- Try sudo in front of cmds in case its permissions stopping flatpak reaching
  your repo.
- You can add the switch `--ostree-verbose` to flatpak cmds to see debug from
  ostree on what any problem might be.
- You can inspect an ostree repo with `ostree summary -v --repo=REPO` to see
  what's actually in it.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: I have this working right up to the last step: I can't get it to install from USB on an offline PC.  You mentioned "If the target is truly offline you can add a remote from a .flatpakrepo file" - could you please elaborate how to do that? (I thought the whole point of creating USB was to be able to install offline - but it always says "Unable to load metadata from remote flathub"....)

Comment: Thanks for your edits. I'd note that I'm downloading them to be used for future offline installs on the same system, so adding if-not-exists doesn't work; I presume the solution is just to add it as a remote of a different name, i.e. flatpak remote-add flathublocal flathub.flatpakrepo. That way when installing online I refer to flathub, and when installing offline I refer to flathublocal.  However, assuming that's correct, even that doesn't work offline; now it becomes "error: Unable to load summary from remote flathublocal: Error resolving “dl.flathub.org”: Name or service not known

Comment: @Metal450 You're welcome. My use-case is different - a purely offline machine - which might explain our different results. However I would have thought you don't have to add the repo twice at all - flatpak should recognise that you have an offline mirror available as long as it can find the files at one of the ostree dirs mentioned above.

Comment: Likewise, I never would've imagined they'd make something seemingly so simple - to install software without an internet connection - so amazingly difficult. On Windows+Mac, you just download an installer. Done. On Snappy it's a bit more of a hassle, but ultimately comes down to just downloading a .snap/.ack that you can use later. Apt is worse still, but thanks to apt-offline you can grab all the debs you need. Flatpak?  More than a week of effort and I *still* can't figure out how to do the absolute most basic thing: install software without having to be tied to the internet :P

Comment: In any case, any idea how to get around the next block: "error: Unable to load summary from remote flathublocal: Error resolving “dl.flathub.org”: Name or service not known"?

Comment: @Metal450 you do not need to add the remote again, you will be fine with just flathub. I think the problem lies elsewhere. See my update that clarifies exact dir layout. Your error message is because it cannot find your offline repo and instead tries online again. I will post comment below with exact script that works for your situation.

Comment: @Metal450 Tested on a brand new Fedora 32 machine, scripts are in quotes run as superuser: "
flatpak remote-add flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo ; 
flatpak remote-modify --collection-id=org.flathub.Stable flathub ; 
flatpak update ; 
flatpak install -y flathub org.gimp.GIMP ; 
flatpak create-usb ./ org.gimp.GIMP ; 
mkdir -p /.ostree/repos.d ; 
mv ./.ostree/repo /.ostree/repos.d/myoffline_repo". Now uninstall GIMP now before we go offline: "flatpak uninstall org.gimp.GIMP -y". NOW GO OFFLINE, ensure ping 8.8.8.8 fails. Then: "flatpak install flathub org.gimp.GIMP".

Comment: @Metal450 stackexchange ruined my script :facepalm find "flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo" in script above and put https:// back in front of it before you run.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Since I couldn't get this working I actually ended up abandoning flatpak & seeking out alternative ways to install everything I need (apt-offline/snappy/appimage), but this will be a great resource to have if/when I find myself needing flatpak to install something else in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

please see this blog on how to install a flatpak offline:
https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2018/08/26/about-flatpak-installations/

Which was referenced by flatpaks original documentation:
https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/usb-drives.html?highlight=offline

enjoy ;-)